# Using Xftp to connect ftpzilla server on windows, can't open the directory

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I'm using Xftp to connect ftpzilla server on windows, but it seems cannot open the directory

here are the details:

the server just repeat this two lines

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| command | PWD |
| Response | 257 "/" is current directory |

I changed the Virtual path to / and native path to C:\ , but it seems not work